# Error when compiling a cydia tweak

Tags: compilation, terminal, theos, cydia

So I have been working on a simple tweak and it literally took me 5 minutes to get the code written. However, I am getting this error now while I compile the tweak! 
Here is the error:

```
Making all for tweak UltraVipPro...
`Making all for tweak UltraVipPro...
 Preprocessing Tweak.xm...
 Compiling Tweak.xm...
 Linking tweak UltraVipPro...
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
 "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UIAlertView", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in Tweak.xm.9fe5fe6c.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [obj/UltraVipPro.dylib.ba964c90.unsigned] Error 1
make[1]: *** [internal-library-all_] Error 2
make: *** [UltraVipPro.all.tweak.variables] Error 2
```

The make file code is here:

```
export ARCHS = armv7 armv7s arm64
export TARGET = iphone:clang:8.1:8.1
export SDKVERSION=8.1

include theos/makefiles/common.mk


TWEAK_NAME = UltraVipPro
UltraVipPro_FILES = Tweak.xm
UltravipPro_FRAMEWORKS = UIKit

include $(THEOS_MAKE_PATH)/tweak.mk

after-install::
   install.exec "killall -9 SpringBoard"
```

Please help me!

Answer (score 1):

1- Make sure that you have this in your Tweak.xm file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
```

2- If that doesn't work, remove that header file import and use this instead:

```
@interface SpringBoard : NSObject
@end
```

Answer (score -1):

im using this :

```
ARCHS = armv7 arm64
```

instead of this :

```
export ARCHS = armv7 armv7s arm64
```

remove the ***export***